# Nodejs CORS not working on some express routes,

Tags: node.js, angular, http-status-code-502

I am using 'cors' module to enable CORS on my EXPRESS APP, but its not Working on two of my routes, I am deploying on google app engine, uploading files on google cloud storage.

```
app.post('/image',cors(corsOptions), authenticateVerifiedadmin, multer.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (!req.file) {
        res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
        return;
    }
    var eventID = _.pick(req.body, ['eventID']);
    const gcsname = eventID.eventID + req.file.originalname;
    const blob = bucket.file(gcsname);
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
        resumable: false
    });
    blobStream.on('error', (err) => {
        next(err);
    });
    blobStream.on('finish', () => {
        var cloudStorageObject = gcsname;
        file.makePublic().then(() => {
            var cloudStoragePublicUrl = getPublicUrl(gcsname);

            Event.findOne({
                _id: eventID.eventID
            }).then(event => {
                debugger;
                event.images.push({
                    imageurl: cloudStoragePublicUrl
                })
                return event.save().then(() => {
                    res.status(200).send()

                }).catch((e) => {
                    res.status(400).send()

                })
            })
        });

        //debugger;
        // console.log(req.files)


    })
})
```

I get 502 status code every time, other routes are working fine.
missing something???

Comment: 502 is *Bad Gateway* so your problem is not related to CORS

Comment: Yes i just figured it out just now, there was typo in bucket name in my configs.